# Rhino explicitly required for Jawr's LESS Processor

Tags: java, maven, jawr

`jawr-core` has the following dependency (see [artifact details](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cnet.jawr%7Cjawr-core%7C3.6%7Cjar)):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mozilla</groupId>
    <artifactId>rhino</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

When processing LESS files I'm facing an exception saying `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mozilla/javascript/ScriptableObject`

If adding rhino dependency explicitly with scope compile to my project the exception is gone.

But why Jawr has a dependency on it with scope provided when it is required to process LESS files?

The servlet container my webapp is running on is Tomcat 7.

Comment: Not sure if I can answer the question direclty, but jawr have made all their dependencies `provided`. It looks to me like they are really worried about getting in the way of your server's classpath (At this link https://jawr.java.net/docs/postprocessors.html#YUI_compressor, they state: "_which might be problematic if you already have rhino on your server's classpath._"). Can only presume that is why they are all provided. You then explicitly need to include the dependencies that you require for the functionality of jawr that you use.

Comment: Sure. You can provide it as an answer.

Comment: Additional: I needed to add lesscss-engine instead of rhino

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jawr have made all their dependencies `provided`, not just the rhino dependency.

It looks to me like they are really worried about getting in the way of your server's classpath.

At this link: http://jawr.java.net/docs/postprocessors.html#YUI_compressor, they state the following:

> *...which might be problematic if you already have rhino on your server's classpath...*

Can only presume that is why they are all provided. You then explicitly need to include the dependencies that you require for the functionality of jawr that you want to use.